# C# Linq: Return a multidimensional array from a list of Object

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array

Say you have a list of Object person:

```
private List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();
```

In which person is defined as:

```
public class Person
{
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public int Age { get; set; }

      public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Can you use Linq to return a multidimensional array from the mentioned list in which the first dimension is index of record, the second dimension is name and the third dimension is email?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Can you provide the expected definition of such multidimensional array? Please note that the index of the array has to be an integer (as far is I know). So how can the `Name` for example be a dimension?  Are you trying to create some kind of dictionary that you can give it a `Name`, `Age`, and a `Mail` and it will give you back a `Person` object?

Comment: I meant to say "give it an Index, Name and Email"

Comment: Yacoub, Jon's answer is exactly what I wanted to do. for example:
String[][] array = lstPersons.Select((Person,i) => new String[] { i.ToString(), Person.Name(), Person.Email() }).ToArray();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can create an `object[][]`, yes:

```
object[][] array = people.Select((p, index) => new object[] { index, p.Name, p.Mail })
                         .ToArray();
```

If you wanted an `object[,]`, that's not doable with regular LINQ as far as I'm aware.

If you have the choice though, I'd personally use an anoymous type:

```
var projected = people.Select((p, index) => new { Index = index, p.Name, p.Mail })
                      .ToArray();
```

It depends on what you want to do with the result, of course...

Comment: This is brilliant Jon, Thanks!